# Notebook MSI GT640 - noisy fan - Ubuntu 11.10 x64

Tags: nvidia, laptop, fan, overheating, noise

I have all time this issue when using Ubuntus, the fan (fans?) runs most off the time and between 60%~100% even in idle which is weird. The GPU temperatures are mostly around 80 degrees and I don't think it's right :(

I always use Jupiter with power saving preset and add the line in linux default like this:

```
quiet splash pcie_aspm=force i915.i915_enable_rc6=1
```

So it helps a little (fan just doesn't run all the time 100%...)

What else can I do?

The notebook spec is:

- Core i7-720 (8 threads)
- NVIDIA GTS250M

So it's rather one of the first, not so silent and cold notebooks;), with Core i7 family and without optimus technology (as nvidia GPU is the only graphic card built-in) but anyway I don't have theese strange hot times in Windows 7.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry to only add upon this complaint, but I have the exact same issue and have had even larger issues with other distro's. I wanted to know if this had anything to do with the new 2nd gen i7 / the threading or architecture , or just another HP heat issue. It is depressing because I worry about physical damage at the temp it runs at under medium load and may have to consider switching to VM for the mean time.